# Creation Pivot table for difficult dataSet python

Tags: python, datetime, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

Please help me to understand how can I create Pivot_table or group by for the difficult dataSet.
I tried to create pivot_table:

```
    grouped_table = pd.pivot_table(renamedDf,index=["date","date_1","date_2","date_3", values = col_list] ,aggfunc=np.sum)
```

I received:

```
    File "<ipython-input-107-c87c2a9a3325>", line 1
grouped_table = pd.pivot_table(renamedDf,index=["date","date_1","date_2","date_3", values = col_list] ,aggfunc=np.sum)
    ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Dataset has the following structure:
[DataSet_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UgPN.png)

Expected structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G8Vx.png)

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post sample data in text rather than image. Helps in copy pasting. Also provide exptected output

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan, I expect to have table grouped by different date, date_1, date_2 for future calculating the mean, min, std, max and plot this mean, std and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a syntax error because you didn't close your bracket after index list move it like this.

```
grouped_table = pd.pivot_table(renamedDf,index=["date","date_1","date_2","date_3"], values = col_list ,aggfunc=np.sum)
```